# Rewriterule help in mod rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I know this has been asked a million times, but I can't figure it out . Please help.

This is the original URL:

```
http://booksnearby.in/show_post.php?title=some_words&id=99
```

Which I want it to appear as

```
http://booksnearby.in/show_post/some_words
```

How ?
I been at this for hours now , just can't figure this out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^showpost/(.*)$ http://booksnearby.in/showpost.php?title=$1&id=99
```

This will rewrite `http://booksnearby.in/showpost/titlesearch` to `http://booksnearby.in/showpost.php?title=titlesearch&id=99`

I've hard coded the id above as clearly its impossible to have this rewritten based on the incoming URL.